# Formatting date in Apache JsonToStringStyle

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, date

I am implementing toString methods for my entities. There are a lot of fields of type ZonedDateTime. Unfortunately, it's converted to extremely long text representation:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[
  time=1545826815293,
  areFieldsSet=true,
  areAllFieldsSet=true,
  lenient=true,
  zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo
  [
    id=
    "UTC",
    offset=0,
    dstSavings=0,
    useDaylight=false,
    transitions=0,
    lastRule=null
  ],
  firstDayOfWeek=1,
  minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,
  ERA=1,
  YEAR=2018,
  MONTH=11,
  WEEK_OF_YEAR=52,
  WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,
  DAY_OF_MONTH=26,
  DAY_OF_YEAR=360,
  DAY_OF_WEEK=4,
  DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,
  AM_PM=1,
  HOUR=0,
  HOUR_OF_DAY=12,
  MINUTE=20,
  SECOND=15,
  MILLISECOND=293,
  ZONE_OFFSET=0,
  DST_OFFSET=0
]
```

How can I format it using SimpleDateFormat? 
I tried the example given here:
https://howtodoinjava.com/apache-commons/how-to-override-tostring-effectively-with-tostringbuilder/

```
public class CustomToStringStyle extends ToStringStyle
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void appendDetail(StringBuffer buffer, String fieldName, Object value)
    {
         if (value instanceof Date)
         {
             value = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(value);
         }
         buffer.append(value);
     }
}
```

But in this case, I don't use JSON style of formatting. I can't extend JsonToStringStyle because it's private.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

ZonedDateTime is part of the new Java 8 API while SimpleDateFormat is the old buggy Date formatter. You need to use the new DateFormatter for Java 8 date/time classes.

The JSON you posted however is neither a ZonedDateTime, nor a Date, it is a GregorianCalendar, so not sure whether your problem is really to do with ZonedDateTime as you are saying.

Comment: ZonedDateTime is converted to that string that I have in response. Maybe it's first converted to GregorianCalendar. This field is ZonedDateTime in my DTO. The problem here is not how to map ZonedDateTime to simple data string, but that if I do it like in my example, then the response is not a JSON. I want both, JSON response and nice date.

Answer (score 2):

`GregorianCalendar` is not `Date`, you can convert it to `Date`, then use the code in your link:

```
if (value instanceof calendar)
{
    Date date = new Date(value.getTimeInMillis());
    value = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
}
```

I would suggest to use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package to deal with date and time.

Comment: Is there a way to keep json style with this approach? (JsonToStringStyle ). That's the main point.